# Attempt to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am creating a CustomMediaTransportControls for MediaPlayerElement. In that I want a button to create a CompactOverlay Frame so I added the below code to `public sealed class CustomMediaTransportControls : MediaTransportControls`.

```
public async void CompactOverlayButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        var frame = new Frame();
        compactViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        frame.Navigate(typeof(VideoPlayerPage));
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "";
    });
    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsViewModeAsync(compactViewId, ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
}
```

But when I use these code I am getting an error message in the XAML part.
[image]
If I didn't use the above function there is no error.

**Solution Tried:**

1. Running `netsh winsock reset` in PowerShell
2. Clearing Solution and ReBuilding Solution

**For Reference:**

Here is my entire code

1. [CustomMediaTransportControls.cs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwavh26kbycrm5m/CustomMediaTransportControls.cs?dl=0) - `ResourceDictionary`
2. [MediaPlayerDictionary.xaml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn5si8bkirqh23h/MediaPlayerDictionary.xaml?dl=0) - Derived class from `MediaTransportControls`
3. [VideosPage.xaml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcawefo710xm9rr/VideosPage.xaml?dl=0) - Page where `CustomMediaTransportControls` has been used

Comment: Are the 'CustomVideoControls' something you have developed? Does it use an unsafe{} block in it?

Comment: @Milney I will attach the entire code in the question

Comment: can you provide full xaml code?

Comment: @Hannes I have attached the entire code in the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring a variable compactViewId in your class you should declare it locally only:

```
p̶u̶b̶l̶i̶c̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶a̶c̶t̶V̶i̶e̶w̶I̶d̶ ̶=̶ ̶A̶p̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶V̶i̶e̶w̶.̶G̶e̶t̶F̶o̶r̶C̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶V̶i̶e̶w̶(̶)̶.̶I̶d̶;  /̶/̶   I̶n̶i̶t̶i̶a̶l̶i̶z̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶a̶c̶t̶V̶i̶e̶w̶I̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶C̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶V̶i̶e̶w̶ ̶I̶D̶

//Button click event for CompactOverlayButton to Create a Frame in CompactOverlay mode
public async void CompactOverlayButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        var frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "";
    });
    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsViewModeAsync(ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id, ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
}
```